# Blue Prism Surface Automation over Citrix

Tags: automation, citrix, region, surface

We're experiencing problems spying a Citrix window.

Our team is not able to spy the outline of the Citrix application window once it is launched. We tried full-screen, on the desktop, on the laptop, closing all other windows, and numerous other scenarios. I believe that it is because the sign-in is via internet explorer and once the Citrix application is launched, the application detaches from Blue Prism.

We were working to troubleshoot this issue and are trying to set up a separate business object for the Citrix window. Another problem is that we cannot launch the Citrix .exe file because it does not allow us to input any parameters to log-in that way. We’re now looking into saving the Citrix file as an .ica file (see https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX804493).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use Surface Automation techniques in order to interact with applications launched via Citrix.  Essentially bitmap mapping.
If you are having difficulty attaching to the citrix window itself, try using a dedicated application like citrix receiver and have Blue Prism launch that application.

You could also try checking the windows process running (.exe) once citrix is launched via IE, and then try attaching to that process.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System Internals process monitor to make sure you attach the correct application, [download it for free from Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor)

When you work with Citrix it depends on the mode you are using. Some of the windows will actually be separate windows, use the Active Accessibility mode to spy them. Some other "windows" or tabs are only visual and you will need to use the Region mode to interact with them.

You should probably be aware that BP has a known issue not flushing all unused memory until the process is finished. If you have a large scale SA process that requires a lot of image processing, OCR etc. it should be a design consideration.